# Backbone and delayed destroy event

Tags: backbone.js

Again some simple problem with backbone. Instead of long description here is some sample code:

```
var Group = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        Product: new Products()
    },

    initialize: function(data){
        var _this = this;

        var products = new Products(data.Product);
        this.set('Product', products);

        this.get('Product').each(function(product){
            product.on('destroy', function(){
                _this.trigger('change');
            }, _this);
        });

        this.bind('change', this.update, this);
    },

    update: function(){
        console.info("something changed");

        console.log(this.get('Product').toJSON());
    },

});
```

So group model contains Product-collection, which obviously contains products. In initialize i am trying to make sure that the update method of the group is called example when product is changed and destroyed. All seems to be working nicely, events get called, attributes look great but it fails when I call destroy method in product model. In update I try to print the contents of product collection and what I get is products BEFORE remove is done. If I call this debug line after 500ms timeout, the contents are ok. Product is removed etc.

So according to my understanding the destroy event of product is called and then passed to group before actual removal from collection is done. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone handles the removal of a destroyed model in a collection by listening to the `destroy` event on the models: see the source code for [Backbone.Model - destroy](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-59) and [Backbone.Collection - _onModelEvent](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-105).

The order in which the handlers will be executed is not guaranteed, you will have to use something else. For example, listen to the `destroy`event on the collection which will fire **after** the model is actually removed:

```
initialize: function(data){
    var _this = this;

    var products = new Products(data.Product);
    this.set('Product', products);

    this.get('Product').on("destroy", this.update, this);
    this.bind('change', this.update, this);
},
```

Check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NUtmt/ for a complete example.